# Custom Web Browser Written in Java Not Functioning: Rendering and Links not Working

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee

I'm making a simple Java Web Browser, it does load webpages from the URL but somehow they don't seem correct at all:

[image]

Plus buttons and links on the page don't work. I think it's something regarding HTML or JS. I'm using Eclipse if that's useful for you.
What am I missing?

[My code](http://pastebin.com/khisTAet)

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class WebBrowser
{
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
          JFrame frame = new EditorPaneFrame();
          frame.show();
     }
}
class EditorPaneFrame extends JFrame
{
     private JTextField url;
     private JCheckBox editable;
     private JButton Carica;
     private JButton Indietro;
     private JEditorPane editorPane;
     private Stack urlStack = new Stack();
     public EditorPaneFrame()
     {
          setTitle("Java Web Browser");
          setSize(600,400);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          setVisible(true);
          // set up text field and load button for typing in URL
          String protocollo = new String ("http://");
          url = new JTextField(protocollo,30);
          Carica = new JButton("Load");
          Carica.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
          {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
               {
                    try
                    {
                         // remember URL for back button
                         urlStack.push(url.getText());
                         editorPane.setPage(url.getText());
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                         editorPane.setText("Error: " +e);
                    }
               }
          });
          // set up back button and button action
          Indietro = new JButton("Back");
          Indietro.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
          {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
               {
                    if(urlStack.size()<=1) return;
                    try
                    {
                         urlStack.pop();
                         String urlString = (String)urlStack.peek();
                         url.setText(urlString);
                         editorPane.setPage(urlString);
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                         editorPane.setText("Error : " +e);
                    }
               }
          });
          editorPane = new JEditorPane();
          editorPane.setEditable(false);
          editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener()
          {
               public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event)
               {
                    if(event.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED)
                    {
                         try
                         {
                              urlStack.push(event.getURL().toString());
                              url.setText(event.getURL().toString());
                              editorPane.setPage(event.getURL());
                         }
                         catch(IOException e)
                         {
                              editorPane.setText("Error: " + e);
                         }
                    }
               }
          });
          editable = new JCheckBox();
          editable.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
          {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
               {
                    editorPane.setEditable(editable.isSelected());
               }
          });
          Container contentPane = getContentPane();
                        contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(editorPane), "Center");
                        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                        panel.add(Indietro);
                        panel.add(new JLabel("URL"));
                        panel.add(url);
                        panel.add(Carica);
                        contentPane.add(panel,"North");
     }
}
```

Comment: Pastebin is not permanent... you should always include code in the question to help future users who find your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the rendering engine that java uses for HTML content within JEditorPanes has not been updated in a while and therefore is not rendering your page correctly. According to [JEditorPane with Javascript and CSS support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717769/jeditorpane-javascript-and-css-support) there is only support up to HTML 3.2 and an initial set of CSS, so JEditorPane does not support HTML 5.

Have a look at the following questions and their answers:

- [Java - HTML5 alternative to JEditorPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218572/java-html5-alternative-to-jeditorpane)
- [JEditorPane with Javascript and CSS support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717769/jeditorpane-javascript-and-css-support)
- [jEditorPane as a web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153806/jeditorpane-as-a-web-browser)

As stated in other answer(s) you could look at alternatives such as Java FX components or http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp .

Comment: I'm thinking of using the WebView from JavaFX, but how can i enable JavaFX on Eclipse? I mean I don't know how to ' import javafx.* '

Answer (score 0):

You are using `JEditorPane` so `javascript` and other `scripts` will not work.
You can use `JWebPane` which internally uses `webkit`.